# How do a #defined function work in C?

Tags: function

I have this piece of code which output is 4. I assumed the answer be 3 because of the pre-increment. Can anyone explain this??

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<cstdio>
    #define MAX(A,B) ((A>B)? A : B)
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        int i=1,j=2,k;
        k= MAX(++i,++j);

        cout<<k;
        return 0;
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#define` does not work like a function, think of it more like a find and replace so doing the macro expansion manually you get

```
int main()
{
    int i=1,j=2,k;
    k= ((++i > ++j) ? ++i : ++j);

    cout<<k;
    return 0;
}
```

This means you increment `i` and `j` once when you compare then, and increment the larger of the two another time before assigning it to `k`. I generally avoid including pre and post increment instructions inside of over logic since it is harder to reason about. You are better just incrementing `i` and `j` on their own lines before using them in `MAX`

Answer (score 0):

Macros are not functions, they just perform text substitution pre-compile time. Your line of code becomes

```
k=((++i>++j)? ++i : ++j);
```

which clearly increments j twice.

Comment: I assumed it. But I had no clear idea. Thanks a lot. Now I am clarified :)

Answer (score 0):

It's called the conditional operator (or ternary operator) which is used in macro substitution

```
#define MAX(a,b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
```

Means:

```
if ((a) > (b)){   
  return a;  
} else {   
  return b; 
}
```

So if you would do:

```
int test = MAX(5,10);
```

test would be 10

Comment: I knew about the ternary operator. And this is all about the macro. Now I got the answer. Thanks for answer.